# Use port forwarding with masquerade

Tags: networking, router, debian, iptables

I'm using a debian as a router with nat configured. How can I set up port forwarding, to set an rdp server on the local network for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is 'Destination NAT' aka DNAT.

I assume you're using plain `iptables` here and that you've already set up SNAT (to route back). Then just do something like this:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3389 \
  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
```

where `eth0` is your WAN interface and `192.168.1.2` is some address in your local network.